# How to fix table in Access DB connect throught Java 8?

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have this code to connect to Access Database with UCanAcess library.

```
      public Visualizzazioni_Access() {
        try {
            log=new MyLog4J();

            File dbFile = new File("CassaGestionale.accdb");
            String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
            db=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path);
            connesso=true;
            System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            connesso=false;
            log.logStackTrace(e);
        }
    }
```

The code works, so when I try to connect I have this debug message? It's an error or not?

```
DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (DatabaseImpl.java:831) - Finished reading system catalog.  Tables: [CodScontrini, Scontrini]
WARNING:Error in the metadata of the table CodScontrini: table's row count in the metadata is 373 but 374 records have been found and loaded by UCanAccess. All will work fine, but it's better to repair your database.
 WARN [AWT-EventQueue-0] (IndexData.java:328) - unsupported data type BINARY for index, making read-only
Connection Succesfull
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because an inconsistency has been detected between the number of records actually found and the number of records registered in the metadata for the table named "CodScontrini".
This doesn't cause issues but by using the [Compact and Repair Database](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Help-prevent-and-correct-database-file-problems-by-using-Compact-and-Repair-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2) feature in Access you can easily restore the table metadata into a correct state from the previous state which had some degree of corruption.